# Article ''the'' in front of word ''research''

Tags: articles

Which one is correct

- According to the research, there is increase in market cap.
- According to research, there is increase in market cap.

When article ''the '' should use in front of word ''research''?

In the following link some people said there is no need of article in front of word ''research''.

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/use-of-definite-article-the-in-front-of-uncountable-noun.2367613/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Research can be used as an uncountable noun for the general body of information on a topic. Alternatively, you could be referring to a specific study/work, which would then be used with the article.

> Research suggests that the increase will continue for the next several years

vs.

> The research of Dr Smith indicate that the situation will resolve itself by next year

For your examples, depending on the specific context, either could be correct.

> According to the research, there is [an] increase in market cap.

Would be more typical if the work referred to a specific scope of research (the work of a particular person, university, a single study, etc).

> According to research, there is [an] increase in market cap.

Would be more typical if the work is referring to research as an abstract quality.

Answer (score 1):

> Sports and academic subjects do not require articles.

from: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/articles/

In my opinion **research** is an academic subject. Therefore you don't need an article.

If you refer to exactly one research activity, which was described before, then there'll be a reason to address that specific research and you'll be able to add the definite article.

***Note: I am neither a native speaker nor an expert - I am just trying to help.***

Comment: I wouldn't classify "research" as an academic subject, especially not in this case. It's not equivalent to saying "According to chemistry"

Comment: I agree - you summed it up pretty nicely by your explanation below. 'Research can be used as an uncountable noun for the general body of information on a topic.'

Answer (score 0):

From reference: http://www.partsofspeech.net/what-is-article/
I will say that if you are meant to a specific research, you have to use 'the' before it

Comment: Please note you must disclose your affiliation with any products or websites linked in your answers, if you have any. See [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/359794).

Comment: Also, a note to learners: that site is full of grammatical and spelling errors.