# "nearby" or "the nearby"?

Tags: articles, idiomatic-language

> That is true in **nearby possible worlds** too.
>
> That is true in **the nearby possible** worlds too.

Which one of the above sentences is more idiomatic. "Nearby" seems to me one of those words that require "the". Does it?

Comment: This issue is addressed  here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/141517/article-the-in-front-of-word-research

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Nearby* is a modifier.

Modifiers don't change the reason why or why you don't use an article/determiner.

Neither of your sentences is more idiomatic than the other.  They communicate different meanings.

> That is true in nearby possible worlds too (Any worlds which fall in the category/type of "nearby possible."  There aren't necessarily any nearby possible worlds in mind yet.)
>
> That is true in the nearby possible worlds too (There are some nearby possible worlds that the speaker/reader is expecting you to know which ones he/she is talking about, and she is referring to them.)

Comment: Good answer. You might like to take a look at another unanswered question  here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150238/is-to-satisfy-a-connection-idiomatic-in-the-mentioned-text